# Does an infinite loop decrease performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, background

So I am currently working on a C#.NET project which checks the current CPU usage and temperature in the background, based on `Performance Counters`.
What it does, is that it retrieves this information with a constant two-second delay.

Like this:

```
while (true)
{
    Foo ();
    Thread.Sleep (2000);
}
```

The output type of my application is a Console Application, contains no GUI and runs in the background.

My question is, does this task decrease performance on the computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you removed that Thread.Sleep(2000); from your code, you would notice your CPU usage go through the roof. Depending on what kind of tasks you have inside that loop.

Comment: A prefer to use a WaitHandle to block instead of a sleep.  The sleep keeps on waking up while the waithandle does nothing : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *does this task decrease performance on the computer?*  No, your computer still provides the same performance; indeed it provides the same performance whatever code you run on it.  A much more interesting question might be *Does this task decrease the useful work the computer does ?*

Comment: Having an infinite loop is pretty sketch, in my experience. I'd recommend using a System.Timer object instead, with an interval of 2000 (milliseconds), and have it do "Foo()" on the elapsed event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: @SvenLion Actually, the only thing the program does is that it retrieves specific details from a Performance Counter about the current CPU usage. So I was doubting if this is maybe a big task or not.

Comment: If you just run an empty program with only a while (true) loop that has nothing inside of it, in my test laptop (i5-6200U @ 2.30GHz) it costs around 30% CPU usage. When I put the Thread.Sleep(1) which is 1ms. The CPU usage goes down to 0% even if it's a minuscule delay it will still make a lot of difference. But that's just CPU usage.

Comment: @SvenLion Thanks a lot for the testing! This means that no matter which delay you choose, if it's higher or equal to 1 millisecond, you won't cause a CPU burn-in.

Comment: @KeesvanVoorthuizen Well, the 1ms doesn't matter, it's just the smallest delay you can put in a Thread Sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't decrease the performance of the computer, since you're sleeping the thread in between every action. As far as I know, sleeping a thread doesn't much cost on the CPU (it's almost a non operation after all).

As Sven has mentioned in the comments, if you were to say, remove the thread sleep from you example, that would change everything, because you would basically be asking your CPU to perform the `Foo` operation as many times a second as it can.